# How do I renew a visa to enter the US from Bolivia?

Tags: visas, bolivia

What document is necessary for a Bolivian national currently in Bolivia to renew a visa for travel to the US?

Comment: http://bolivia.usembassy.gov/visa_services.html

Comment: Have you googled "visa for the us?". (honest question)

Answer (score -2):

You'll need (full list [here](http://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/files/form/i-539instr.pdf)):

- The I-94 [form](http://www.cbp.gov/i94)
- Your passport
- The filled in I-539 [form](http://www.uscis.gov/i-539)

You can apply online or by mail and they recommend applying at least 45 days before your stay expires.

Note your current visa must be still valid otherwise you need to apply for a new one, quoting [CIS](http://www.uscis.gov/visit-united-states/extend-your-stay):

> If you want to extend your stay in the United States,
>   you must file a request with U.S. Citizenship and Immigration Services
>   (USCIS) on the Form I-539, Application to Extend/Change Nonimmigrant
>   Status **before your authorized stay expires**. [...]
>
> **You may apply to extend your stay if:**
>
> - You were lawfully admitted into the United States with a nonimmigrant
>     visa
> - **Your nonimmigrant visa status remains valid**
> - You have not committed any crimes that make you ineligible for a visa You have not
>     violated the conditions of your admission
> - Your passport is valid and
>     will remain valid for the duration of your stay

Comment: Is this really an answer to the question? It seems to assume that the applicant is in the US, whereas the question explicitly says that the person is **currently in Bolivia**.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I know, but neither CIS or the Department of State made that distinction

Comment: The form you link to says that it can be filed by "[n]onimmigrants in the United States", which seems to exclude noimmigrants in Bolivia pretty clearly.

Comment: @HenningMakholm it also says you can apply online, and Bolivia falls in the Lima USCIS field office jurisdiction (waiting for their official answer about this)